# Databinding to a window"s property doesn't work

Tags: wpf, data-binding, properties

I can't figure out what am I doing wrong and why my the text doesn't show up.

```
<Window x:Class="Test"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Test" Height="300" Width="300" x:Name="TheWindow">

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=TheWindow,Path=TestObject, Mode=OneTime}" FontSize="12"></TextBlock>
```

And the code behind the window:

```
    public partial class Test : Window
{
    public Test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public const string TestObject = "I just want to be shown";
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can only bind to properties, read some references first...

(In this case you would use [`x:Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx), still, [*read the references*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx))